# How do I disable comment auto approval?

Tags: comments

I have comments that are being auto approved in Drupal and I'd like to disable that.  I want to approve comments before they are published.

Comment: A better approach might be to only require approval of a user's FIRST comment. This can be done using https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_trust

Answer (score 17):

If a comment is 'auto approved' as you call it, depends on the user's permissions. To change it, log in as administrator, go to `/admin/user/permissions#module-comment` and make sure that the 'post comments without approval' permission is not set for roles that are not allowed to post comments without approval.

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 7 authenticated (logged in) users have the 'Skip comment approval' property set by default. This can be changed at `/admin/people/permissions/list#module-comment` to put the comments in an approval queue, before they are published.